# get common string from array on toggle

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Im using SelectionModel for mat-checkbox and im calling a function on each click :

```
 toggleSelection(row) {
    this.selection.toggle(row);
    console.log("Selection");
    console.log("this", this.selection.selected);
    this.selection.selected.forEach(selected => {
      this.masterPossibleActions = this.masterPossibleActions.filter(action => selected.possibleActions == action);
    });
    console.log(":MAster",this.masterPossibleActions)
  }
```

this.selection.selected is returning array of objects representing selected rows . There is a propery called possibleActions on each object. I want the masterPossibleActions Array to be the list of possible actions common between all selected rows.

PossibleACtion object class:

```
class ActionObject {
  key: string;
  value: string;
  constructor(key: string, value: string) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

The toggle function:

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat-checkbox appClickStopPropagation (change)="toggleSelection(row)" class="custom-checkbox"
            [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </td>
```

this.selection is:

```
  selection = new SelectionModel<Enrolment>(true, []);
```

Enrolment object:

```
 export class Enrolment {
  id: string;
  user: any;
  enrollable: any;
  time_created: string;
  status: string;
  possibleActions: Array<ActionObject> = [];

  preparePossibleActions() {
    this.possibleActions = [];
    this.possibleActions.push(new ActionObject("DELETE", "Delete"));
    switch (this.status) {
      case "PENDING":
        this.possibleActions.push(new ActionObject("REMOVE", "Reject"));
        this.possibleActions.push(new ActionObject("APPROVE", "Approve"));
        break;
      case "REJECTED":
      case "CANCELLED":
      case "WITHDRAWN":
        break;
      case "APPROVED":
      case "WITHDRAW_PENDING":
      case "COMPLETED":
        this.possibleActions.push(new ActionObject("REMOVE", "Withdraw"));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  constructor(rawObj: any) {
    this.id = rawObj.id;
    this.user = rawObj.user;
    this.enrollable = rawObj.enrollable;
    this.time_created = rawObj.time_created;
    this.status = rawObj.status;
    this.preparePossibleActions();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the problem you are adressing is how to filter correctly. 
You could try:

```js
// masterPossibleActions is combined actions from all rows (array)
// this.selection.selected is all selected rows (need to call possibleActions)
let actions = this.selection.selected.map(selectedRow => selectedRow.possibleActions)
// initialize masterPossibleActions with first element -> can only shrink not grow because there wont be any actions that aren't in first element action's and common between all of them
this.masterPossibleActions = actions[0]
// filter the initial value to fit only common actions
this.masterPossibleActions = this.masterPossibleActions.filter(action => {
  let isCommon = true
  actions.forEach(rowActions => {
    if (rowActions.indexOf(action) < 0 ) {
      isCommon = false
    }
  })
  return isCommon
})
```

final function:

```js
 toggleSelection(row) {
    this.selection.toggle(row);
    this.masterPossibleActions = actions[0]
    this.masterPossibleActions = this.masterPossibleActions.filter(action => {
      let isCommon = true
      actions.forEach(rowActions => {
        if (rowActions.indexOf(action) < 0 ) {
           isCommon = false
        }
      })
      return isCommon
    })
  }
```

Comment: i want to create a final array with the common elements instead of returning a boolean

Comment: thats what it does, the boolean is inside the filter function to determine whether the action is common between all of them or not. `return isCommon`therefore just returns the boolean for filtering.

Comment: does it fit your needs? Maybe I've misunderstood something.

Comment: the masterPossible action is filtering out on selection of second item.. It is becoming empty. i want it to work like .. if for first row it is [1,2] and also for second row [1,2] ,i want master possible action to be [1,2] .. now it returns [].. if [1,3] and [1,2] ,it should be [1]

Comment: it could be any number of rows,  [1,2],[1,3],[1,4] should return [1]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-array-filter
Tried to build it as close to what you described as possible.

Comment: i think the problem is because the function gets called on each selection of a row.. it called when each new row is selected

Comment: Can you maybe show what the toggle function does?
You could just keep track of which rows are selected and which are not. Maybe with an array/set/... and whenever you de-/select a row remove/add it to the array/set/...

Comment: I have updated the question. The togg;le function is for toggliong the checkbox @mortom123

Comment: You didn't share the `toggle` function, only the checkbox. Nevertheless did I rewrite the demo to be more fitting for your example (I assume). Tell me if its working now. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-array-filter

Comment: toggle function is an inbuild function of SelectionModel..It just toggles the checkbox selectioon

Comment: i have updated the question with what selection is. Can you make this logic work with this SelectionModel

Comment: Oh. My bad. 
Yes demo link is the same as above. Works now. I opted to use the `change` EventEmitter of the SelectionModel to seperate selection logic into smaller bis.

Comment: it has issues.my possible actrions array is an array of dictionary instead of numbers. The same isnt working for me .can you check?

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete Enrolment class

Comment: Changed it. (Link is the same)
Note: (take a look at the `updateMasterActions` function:
The problem is, i was simply checking if an object is part of the Array but since you generated new `actionobjects` everytime a new `enrolment` was generated the objects weren't the same. I opted to refactor this code a little and make the objects static attribute inside the `ActionObject` class, therefore not generating new ones but referencing old ones. But I also wrote a second filter function in case you wanna stick with your way of doing things.

Comment: The second filter function doesnt work as expected. when i first select second option and then the second,it still shows three options.can you check?

Comment: i dont want to preselect an option

Comment: No preselect -> Simply don't do it. 
Sadly, I'm not able to understand exactly what you mean, Feel free to post a stackblitz link.

Comment: I was able to achive the result using static variables. THe issue was with the second option you had given